# Comment out an include statement inside an HTML file using Jekyll

Tags: comments, jekyll

Is there a way to comment out an include statement inside an HTML file using Jekyll?

For example I have this inside one of my HTML files that I'd like to temporarily comment out. Standard  HTML comment doesn't seem to work.

```
{% include navbar.html %}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
{% comment %}
{% include navbar.html %}
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 23):

Jekyll uses the [Liquid templating system](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/). So whatever works for Liquid works for Jekyll.

```
{% comment %}
this is commented out
{% endcomment %}
```

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/template/#comment

Answer (score 1):

mccambridge posted the correct solution. The one posted by David Jacquel does not work in Jekyll.
In alternative you can add a space between the bracket **{** and the percentage simbol **%** like shown below:

```
{% comment %}
{ % include navbar.html % }
{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 0):

since jekyll is used inside of html i think it's better to do it this way

1. make a space between the brackets and percent sign
2. wrap it in an html comment

```html
<div>
    <!-- { % for i in (1..100) % } -->
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        <a href="{{post.url}}"> {{post.title}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- { % endfor % } -->
    
</div>
```

the above code is a very common use case for me where i want to simulate a lot of posts to debug my ui